# JS template solution for transforming DOM elements into HTML tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, html-table

I'm working on a project that has normal HTML content generated dynamically based on JSON data. Effectively I don't have access to the JSON data by the time this question comes into play. I need to take the HTML that's in the DOM, comb through it, and create a "table view" mode for the content on the page.  The tables will be nested inside of each other as well as stacked on top of each other, if that matters.  Normally I would loop through each element, loop through all the `<label>` values at a certain scope, make the `<thead>`, etc. but I've been instructed to use some sort of template plugin/system.

Does anyone have a strong recommendation for templating where the flow is:

**HTML -> JS manipulation -> HTML table**

Here's an obfuscated & simplified example of the HTML I need to make my table from.

```
<div id="test3">
    <h1>Top Level</h1>
    <div class="fn_Name" fieldtype="hidden">
        <div class="errorDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldHolder fn_Protocol_Name" fieldtype="text">
        <div class="label">Protocol Name*</div>
        <div class="field">Value One</div>
        <div class="errorDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldHolder fn_Protocol_Description" fieldtype="text">
        <div class="label">Protocol Description*</div>
        <div class="field">Value Two</div>
        <div class="errorDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldHolder fn_Measurement_Labels" fieldtype="text">
        <div class="label">Measurement Labels*</div>
        <div class="field">Value Three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fn_Red_Components" fieldtype="heading">
        <h2>Red Components</h2>
        <div class="errorDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldHolder fn_Red_Component_Fields fieldSetHolder" fieldtype="fieldSet">
        <div class="label">Red Component Fields</div>
        <div class="field">
            <div class="fieldHolder fs_Red_Component_Fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="fieldHolder">
                        <div class="field fieldSetField">
                            <div class="fn_Red_Component" fieldtype="heading">
                                <h2>Red Component</h2>
                                <div class="errorDiv"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fieldHolder fn_Red_Component_Name" fieldtype="text">
                                <div class="label">Red Component Name*</div>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="fieldValue">
                                        Red Component Value
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="errorDiv"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fieldHolder fn_Red_Component_Role" fieldtype="select">
                                <div class="label">Red Component Role*</div>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="fieldValue">
                                        A red component role val
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="errorDiv"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fieldHolder fn_Owner_Birth_Name" fieldtype="text">
                                <div class="label">Owner Birth Name</div>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="fieldValue">
                                        Tommy
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="errorDiv"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fieldHolder fn_Red_Component_Type_Fields fieldSetHolder" fieldtype="fieldSet">
                                <div class="label">Red Component Type Fields</div>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="fieldHolder fs_Red_Component_Type_Fields">
                                        <div class="field">
                                            <div class="fieldHolder">
                                                <div class="field fieldSetField">
                                                    <div class="fn_Component_Type" fieldtype="heading">
                                                        <h2>Component Type</h2>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="fieldHolder fn_Red_Component_Type" fieldtype="select">
                                                        <div class="label">Red Component Type</div>
                                                        <div class="field">
                                                            <div class="fieldValue">
                                                                Some Value
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="errorDiv"></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="fieldHolder fn_Red_Dog_Name" fieldtype="select" style="">
                                                        <div class="label">Red Dog Name*</div>
                                                        <div class="field">
                                                            <div class="fieldValue">

                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="fieldHolder fs_Red_Component_Type_Fields">
                                        <div class="field">
                                            <div class="fieldHolder">
                                                <div class="field fieldSetField">
                                                    <div class="fn_Component_Type" fieldtype="heading">
                                                        <h2>Component Type</h2>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="fieldHolder fn_Red_Component_Type" fieldtype="select">
                                                        <div class="label">Component</div>
                                                        <div class="field">
                                                            <div class="fieldValue">
                                                                Some Value
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="errorDiv"></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="fieldHolder fn_Some_Name" fieldtype="select" style="">
                                                        <div class="label">Red Dog Name*</div>
                                                        <div class="field">
                                                            <div class="fieldValue">

                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> </div>
```

Comment: if you can post a sample of the html we can take a crack at it...

Comment: Coming right up...